# Is it possible to check if a value is within a range using count method?

Tags: python, list, count

I have a data structure of lists where the format is `(<string>, <integer in {1,2,3}>)`. One string could have different int values associated with it.

Is it possible to use the count function to count the number of elements in the structure that could qualify for the expected int?

For example,

```
[("y",1), ("y",3), ("n",1), ("y",1)]
```

`<structure>.count(("y", <code>))`

The `<code>` should check to see if that index of the list is either 1, 2, or 3. In that case, it would return 3.

Comment: TLDR: you want to count the number of ("y", *any number*) tuples in the list?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass in the tuple as your argument for count.

```
test = [("y",1),("y",3),("n",1),("y",1)]
    
print(test.count(('y', 1)))
print(test.count(('y', 3)))
print(test.count(('n', 1)))
```

Will output

```
2
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach using `sum`:

```
sum(1 for x in lst if x[0] == "y")
```

Alternative approach:

```
next(zip(*lst)).count("y")
```

Edit: simplified code thanks to wjandrea

Comment: Slightly simpler: `sum(1 for x in lst if x[0] == "y")`

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, they also want to check that the int is any of 1, 2, or 3. So that would be: `sum(1 for x in lst if x[0] == "y" and x[1] in {1, 2, 3})`

Comment: Yup, I think you're right in terms of what OP wanted. I took it as, "can you use count function to search for tuples?"